# Google Docs Sharing Container Bound Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i have a simple google doc running a basic script enabling a sidebar containing a playable mp3.

My goal is to be able to share this document with any anonymous user
and have them view the document and script the same way i do.

what steps can i take to make this happen? if i cant use a container bound scrip, how do i make a stand alone sidebar script? and if none of those are possible, is there another option for including audio in a document without having to open it in another tab?

i am extremely amateur at scripts, plz forgive me
and thanks for any info you can share!

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJH63.png

Comment: If you give everyone and anyone edit access, they can open the script editor and view the code.  If you give everyone view access, they can't open the script editor, but they can copy the file, and then they will be the owner of the new file, and can open the script editor.  The bound code gets copied with the file.  You could open source the code and post it in a public repository on GitHub or Bitbucket.  You could use a stand alone script as a library, and give everyone view access to the library code.  Then give people the link to the library.  That's what I would do.

Comment: You could perhaps use google slides instead and insert your audio as a youtube video.

Comment: @SandyGood sounds like way to many install steps involved for me. im looking for more "plug and play" sharing. after doing so research, my goal seems difficult to achieve using Google Docs.

Comment: @JasonAllshorn Can you share a video and play it while staying in the slide?

Comment: Just have a separate apps script stand alone file that is an exact duplicate of the bound project, and have a link that the user can click to go to the stand alone file apps script file to see it.

Comment: @ToddBanacting yes. If you insert the video and double-click it, it will play without leaving the slides. If you right click you can open options and it will play in the sidebar. Best of all you can insert videos from your Google Drive.

Comment: google slides works much better for what i want to do